# Flatten a list inside list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the following list of tuples.

```py
lst = 
    [
        ('LexisNexis', ['IT Services and IT Consulting ', ' New York City, NY']),
        ('AbacusNext', ['IT Services and IT Consulting ', ' La Jolla, California']), 
        ('Aderant', ['Software Development ', ' Atlanta, GA']),
        ('Anaqua', ['Software Development ', ' Boston, MA']),
        ('Thomson Reuters Elite', ['Software Development ', ' Eagan, Minnesota']),
        ('Litify', ['Software Development ', ' Brooklyn, New York'])
    ]
```

I want to flatten the lists in each tuple to be part of the tuples of `lst`.
I found this [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/10543310) but have no idea how to make it adequate to my case.

Comment: So you will need the output as a list of tuples, without the list in the tuples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/):

```py
lst = [('LexisNexis', ['IT Services and IT Consulting ', ' New York City, NY']),
       ('AbacusNext', ['IT Services and IT Consulting ', ' La Jolla, California']), 
       ('Aderant', ['Software Development ', ' Atlanta, GA']),
       ('Anaqua', ['Software Development ', ' Boston, MA']),
       ('Thomson Reuters Elite', ['Software Development ', ' Eagan, Minnesota']),
       ('Litify', ['Software Development ', ' Brooklyn, New York'])]

output = [(x, *l) for (x, l) in lst]

print(output)
# [('LexisNexis', 'IT Services and IT Consulting ', ' New York City, NY'),
#  ('AbacusNext', 'IT Services and IT Consulting ', ' La Jolla, California'),
#  ('Aderant', 'Software Development ', ' Atlanta, GA'),
#  ('Anaqua', 'Software Development ', ' Boston, MA'),
#  ('Thomson Reuters Elite', 'Software Development ', ' Eagan, Minnesota'),
#  ('Litify', 'Software Development ', ' Brooklyn, New York')]
```

Comment: Great resource of PEP Index, I added it to my bookmarks. Thanks, @j1-lee.

Comment: This list comprehension can be in-place. Won't need to create output.  +1 though. I was about to post this before I saw yours.

Comment: How to make it in-place?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30197162/16836078) by Deacon using `abc` from `collections`. It is worth to try it too.

```
from collections import abc

def flatten(obj):
    for o in obj:
        # Flatten any iterable class except for strings.
        if isinstance(o, abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(o, str):
            yield from flatten(o)
        else:
            yield o

[tuple(flatten(i)) for i in lst]
Out[47]: 
[('LexisNexis', 'IT Services and IT Consulting ', ' New York City, NY'),
 ('AbacusNext', 'IT Services and IT Consulting ', ' La Jolla, California'),
 ('Aderant', 'Software Development ', ' Atlanta, GA'),
 ('Anaqua', 'Software Development ', ' Boston, MA'),
 ('Thomson Reuters Elite', 'Software Development ', ' Eagan, Minnesota'),
 ('Litify', 'Software Development ', ' Brooklyn, New York')]
```